# KeyboardDialog for Roku Remote

Tags: java, android, keyboard, roku

i am working on rokuTv remote control app in android java i want to implement keyboard functionality for the same any leads will be appreciate like how to start what to do i just need basic roadmap , Thanks in advance..

expecting suggestions from active users or who already worked on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For keyboard command, You may find some leads for it.
You  can find keyup, keydown, and keypress commands for keyboard characters.

[This is Roku official developer site for commands](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/dev-tools/external-control-api.md#keypress-key-values)

For Keyboard command in apps like Youtube, you can use this:

```bash
$ curl -d '' "http://$ROKU_DEV_TARGET:8060/keypress/Lit_u"
```

In this URL, append the keyboard character after
keypress/Lit_YOURKEYBOARDKEY

For example,
"http://$ROKU_DEV_TARGET:8060/keypress/Lit_a"
"http://$ROKU_DEV_TARGET:8060/keypress/Lit_b"

Comment: Thanks, i already done with those commands now i am working on another module which is whatever i type from app it will display and search on rokuTV btw thanks for answer

Comment: You mean search in the youtube search box for find videos by using keyboard?

Comment: yes , in any channel , i want to implement search functionality

Comment: I have edited my answer for keyboard command.